# input type="date" shows "dd-mm-yyyy" for empty value

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, html-template-directives

let's say i have

```
 <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <input type="date" 
                    id="form-element-expiration-date" 
                    value={expDate}
                    class="slds-input" 
                    readonly/>
        </div>
```

when expDate is empty (undefined in terms of javascript) i always get dd/mm/YYYY value. Is it possible to format somehow the value to be e.g. '' instead of 'dd/ mm / YYYY'

Comment: That would be a place holder which you need to remove. This could help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686288/remove-default-text-placeholder-present-in-html5-input-element-of-type-date

Comment: custom CSS using LWC?